# How to delete last six columns that don't have NaN values of dataframe where each row has a different number of columns with values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a Pandas dataframe with more than two thousand rows and almost a thousand columns. The problem is that each row has a different number of columns that actually have values on them. If the values in a row use fewer columns than the longest row, the remaining values are NaN.

It looks like this:

```
     0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7
A  Hip  22  Hop  Hat    3  NaN  NaN  NaN
B  Gig  45  Get  Gik    4  Goo    5  NaN
C  Lip  34  Lop    2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
D  Fip  56  Fup  Fik  Fap  Fat  Fot  6.0
```

I am trying to remove (and store as a separate dataframe) the last two columns for each row that don't include NaN values. So I want is something like this:

```
     0   1    2    3    4    5    6   7
A  Hip  22  Hop  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
B  Gig  45  Get  Gik    4  NaN  NaN NaN
C  Lip  34  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
D  Fip  56  Fup  Fik  Fap  Fat  NaN NaN
```

I tried to convert the dataframe to a nested list, where I could simply delete the NaN values and remove the last columns of each list, but it crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide your input in a reproducible format (text, not image)?

Answer (score 1):

Compute a mask using [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) on the reversed columns:

```
N = 2 # number of trailing non-NA values
m = df.iloc[:, ::-1].notna().cumsum(axis=1).gt(N)

out1 = df[m]
out2 = df[~m]
```

Output:

```
# out1
     0   1    2    3    4    5    6   7
A  Hip  22  Hop  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
B  Gig  45  Get  Gik    4  NaN  NaN NaN
C  Lip  34  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
D  Fip  56  Fup  Fik  Fap  Fat  NaN NaN

# out2
     0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7
A  NaN NaN  NaN  Hat    3  NaN  NaN  NaN
B  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  Goo    5  NaN
C  NaN NaN  Lop    2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
D  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  Fot  6.0
```

Intermediate mask `m`:

```
      7     6      5      4      3      2      1      0
A  True  True   True   True   True  False  False  False
B  True  True   True  False  False  False  False  False
C  True  True   True   True  False  False  False  False
D  True  True  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this with the DF I am working on.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to have worked perfectly for what I was doing.